# What units does `ps -o` report memory usage in?

Tags: memory, ps, measurement

I'm using a script - memusg - to report the peak memory usage of my rails app.  The script uses `ps -o` to measure memory usage. My question is: what units does `ps -o` report memory usage in?

The script can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/netj/526585).

And, here is the output from a run:

```
$~/bin/memusg rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

<-- snip --> 

$memusg: peak=2607332
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the author's comment on the script's page, he [answered over at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774556/peak-memory-usage-of-a-linux-unix-process/3491573#3491573) and said it is in kilobytes.